# Unable to use USB through DD-WRT on a Buffalo WZR-HP-G300NH2

Tags: mount, usb, samba, router, dd-wrt

I have a Buffalo WZR-HP-G300NH2 and I'm trying to get USB support working. The original Buffalo-branded firmware would refuse to mount the USB drive, so I've followed what [tutorials I've found for DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Buffalo_WZR-HP-G300NH). I've tried ssh-ing into the box and mounting it with

```
mount /dev/sda /mnt
```

as root, and it fails with invalid arguments.

For USB file formats I've tried EXT3 and XFS. XFS is the user-friendly firmware file format.

I can enable FTP in the DD-WRT GUI and log in, but transferring anything bigger then 5MB to the 500GB attached drive causes the router to reboot.

I've downgraded to the Buffalo user-friendly firmware and it seemed to work, but I would like to get DD-WRT running; currently I'm running build 18024.